# wkwebview: know when rendering is finished

Tags: javascript, cocoa, wkwebview

I am modifying in javascript the content of a page loaded in a `WkWebView` and take a screenshot using `takeSnapshotWithConfiguration:completionHandler:` on the completion handler of the javascript.

Unfortunately I am often getting partially rendered page. I would really like to avoid any delay/timer method but I am looking for a "way" to really know when the page finished rendering

Comment: I am facing the same problem trying to find when the page is completely rendered after modifying it using javascript. Have you found some solution for this? many thanks!

Comment: @shin Unfortunately, I am still looking for a reliable way to get this information. I tried various things (mutation observers for instance) but it was still less reliable than a dirty delay. If you find any way to get notified when processing is done, thanks for sharing.